# Gradle Custom Plugin: gradleApi() vs Explicit Dependency

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm developing a custom gradle plugin and the dependencies for my plugin project look like this:

```
dependencies {
  compile gradleApi()
  compile localGroovy()
  compile('com.xxx.oozie:oozie-dsl-parser:1.0.127') {
    exclude module: 'groovy-all'
  }

  testCompile('org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.3') {
    exclude module: 'groovy-all'
  }
}
```

However, in the interest of reproducible builds, I'm wondering if using `localGroovy()` and `gradleApi()` is advisable.

After much googling, although I could replace `localGroovy()` with a specific version of groovy, I can't seem to find a definitive answer on what I would replace `gradleApi()` with.

Do you guys have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Opal.

Comment: And now it's me too. I need to build a Gradle plugin from Maven/Java, but I can't find the notorious `gradleApi()` dependency anywhere. Suffice to say that the decade is actually ending these days with no answer in sight. Gradle seems quite obscure in some respects.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest applying the `java-gradle-plugin`. It adds the `gradleApi()` dependency automatically and also includes some other boilerplate configurations: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/javaGradle_plugin.html#gsc.tab=0

The version of the `gradleApi()` that is added as dependency depends on the Gradle version that you are using the build the project. For example if your wrapper has Gradle 2.14.1 the used Gradle API will be of that version.

You also do not have to worry about `localGroovy()` because it is already included in the `gradleTestKit()` dependency which is added by the plugin: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/test_kit.html#sub:test-kit-automatic-classpath-injection&gsc.tab=0

Here is an example:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'java-gradle-plugin'

dependencies {
    testCompile('org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4') {
        exclude module: 'groovy-all'
    }
}
```

Comment: But still... where's that `gradleApi()` dependency? And how to I specify the specific version I want?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1835 it seems like there is no explicit dependency you can use for that purpose.

Although not equivalent to `gradleApi()`, if you are developing for Android you might be interested in the `com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:3.3.2` dependency.