# Gradle Plugin dependency

Tags: java, gradle, maven-3, gradle-plugin

What is the exact dependency I need to develop a Gradle Plugin in Java? Ideally I would like to get it from a well-known repository such as Maven Central or similar.

I have a Maven project with a core functionality and I just added two extra plugins, one for Ant, one for Maven. They are already tested and working; easy! Now, I wanted to add a third module for a Gradle plugin to make this functionality also available from any Gradle project.

However, I can't find the exact dependencies I need to develop a Gradle plugin.

The Gradle docs (such as https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_gradle_plugin.html) are not very well written to say the least. They mention:

- the `gradleAPI()` dependency
- or the `java-gradle-plugin` dependency

But they are quite unclear... no group, no version (really?).

If anyone can enlighten me to where I can get these dependencies from, I would be very thankful.

Comment: the top voted ans here possibly address your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33906081/gradle-custom-plugin-gradleapi-vs-explicit-dependency

Comment: @NigelSavage Thanks for the link. According to the discussions there it seems that Gradle is not 100% transparent about its internal dependencies. I guess the other option would be to switch my entire project from Maven to Gradle; but I have already the Ant and Maven plugins modules running and tested. Sigh.

Comment: with some refactoring should be able to keep the ant plugin, not sure about the maven one though, but I think you would just declare both as class path dependencies in the buildscript(older not plugins) syntax then apply.

Answer (score 5):

Gradle's public and internal APIs, aka `gradleApi()`, are bundled with the Gradle distribution and not independently published and therefore not easily consumable by Maven builds. There's the pending epic [#1156](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1156) (*Ensure plugin cross-version compatibility by allowing a user to depend on gradlePublicApi()*) that might help here.

Since Gradle plugins are best to be built with Gradle, a pragmatic solution is to invoke the Gradle build from Maven and attach the produced artifact to the Maven build. Andres Almiray ([aalmiray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120745/aalmiray)) once described this in the blog post [Running Gradle Inside Maven](http://andresalmiray.com/running-gradle-inside-maven/) ([Web Archive Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20191205042613/http://andresalmiray.com/running-gradle-inside-maven/)). He describes the following high level steps:

1. Create a new Maven `module` (e.g. `gradle-plugin`) and add attach it to the parent POM
2. In the POM of `gradle-plugin` add a dependency to your `core` module. Use the [maven-dependency-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) to store dependencies to the Maven build folder, e.g. `target/dependencies`.
3. Create the `build.gradle`, add a Maven repository that points to `target/dependencies` (step 2) and let it depend on the `core` module as well as `gradleApi()`. Implement the Gradle plugin.
4. Use the [exec-maven-plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) to invoke the Gradle build.
5. Use the [maven-resources-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/) to copy the Gradle built plugin jars to the standard Maven build folder.
6. Use the [build-helper-maven-plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html) to attach the copied jars to the Maven build.

Sample project to be found [here](https://github.com/aalmiray/gradle-in-maven) (gradle-in-maven).

Comment: Thanks. I think this looks like a workaound that can actually work, (as long as the gradle-api is not officially published). I'm familiar with the maven plugins (except for the last one #6). I'll try it out.

Comment: It works! This workaround work pretty well. I left a few comments in the blog post, since some sections are not entirely clear for a newbie like me. I was able to make it run thought (with a few deprecation warnings I'll tackle in a few) +1.

Comment: @JoeDiNottra Glad to hear that!

Comment: I couldn't fully test it to the end (aka having a running plugin) mainly because of my limited knowledge of Gradle plugin details. However, this is working as a solution to cross build a multi-module project in Maven+Gradle. One extra detail that's worth mentioning is that the pom.xml of the gradle module should disable all compilation (since Maven is unable to compile), using the "maven-compiler-plugin" with "phase: none".

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:custom_plugins_standalone_project

In here it is mentioned that it is `gradleApi()` and I know that this works (from experience). The `localGroovy()` on that page is only needed if your plugin code uses groovy (does not apply if you only use groovy in the build.gradle of your plugin).

java-gradle-plugin is a library that makes it a bit simpler to make plugins, it is not required though. I personally prefer using gradleApi only.

**EDIT:**

It appears I've misunderstood the question. Here are the steps to get gradleApi jar:

1. Create a Gradle project with your desired Gradle version.
2. Add `implementation gradleApi()` dependency.
3. Import/run the project once.
4. Go to your .gradle folder (located in home folder in Linux-based operating systems).
5. Open caches folder
6. Open the version folder you want, e.g. 6.0.1
7. Open generated-gradle-jars folder.
8. Copy the jar to wherever you want and use it.

For me the 6.0.1 jar is at ~/.gradle/caches/6.0.1/generated-gradle-jars/gradle-api-6.0.1.jar

Please note that I have not tested this, I know the jar is there but I haven't tried using it.

Comment: Thanks. Where do I download the `gradleApi()` from? Remember this is not a Gradle project, but a Maven project.

Comment: I don't know why you're compiling a Gradle plugin with Maven, but I've added steps to find the gradleApi() jar. I didn't share my version of it because my Gradle version might not be the same as yours. I hope it works for you @JoeDiNottra

Comment: The version of the Gradle API corresponds to the Gradle distribution used by the project. That version and its download location in turn is usually specified by the Gradle Wrapper ( https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html ) and the `gradleApi()` call just tells it to use the local distribution for developing. The default download source for the distributions is https://services.gradle.org/distributions/

Comment: The gradleApi is a combination of multiple libraries, I believe: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/0e5b6acd39b38253fa00078523472e572794347f/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/DependencyClassPathProvider.java#L66

Comment: I found the `gradle-api-4.3.jar`. It's 101 MB in size. This can't be right. I cannot (should not) upload a library that big on a project. I just want to build a minimal [wrapper] plugin of an existing logic that already works from Ant and Maven.

Comment: Have you at least tried using it so you can know if it is what you want? I don't think it is wrong, because this jar is a combination of other multiple Gradle libraries which in turn probably include other libraries. You don't need to include the library in your final jar, but only when you compile your project. Perhaps you can strip it down to only include what you need?